# Why is "Achievements" under "Education" on Careers?

Tags: discussion, jobs, semantics

The "Achievements" section on my CV is a subsection of the "Education" section. That would make sense if it were for academic achievements like Latin honors. The "help" note on the side, though, suggests you

> Brag about your GPA, your SAT scores, being Employee of the Month at the car wash: whatever you got.

If this section is meant for academic achievement, where do other ones go? And why does the note indicate otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

I am ok with an *Achievements* section for *Education*, but would like to see an *Achievements* section, in addition to *Responsibilities*, for each subsequent *Experience* block in the CV.

I feel like I really started to get things done when I had a real job and that stuff doesn't really belong in *Responsibilities*.