# Can we have Achievements in addtion to Responsibilities in each Experience section?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, jobs

So someone has [asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25923/why-is-achievements-under-education-on-careers) why achievements are under education on Careers.  I answered with a follow up:

Why not have *Achievements* for each *Experience* block?  I was not getting any action, so I thought I would re-state the question.

I feel like I really started to get things done when I had a real job and that stuff doesn't really belong in Responsibilities.

Answer (score 2):

The Achievements for the position should go under that position's `Experience` block, not as a separate heading.

Something like this:

#### Microsoft - 1994-1999

- Created Excel VBA
- Spent the next 9 years talking about it

This is a normal practice for HR, and I realize that as programmers we want to have things clearly delineated, but that's not normal practice for HR companies and hiring managers.

Comment: You are Joel's alter ego? ;)

Comment: so how do you delineate achievements and responsibilities?

Comment: perhaps responsibilities should just be achievements instead?

Comment: Responsibilities and acheivements go together, intermixed under that job heading.

Comment: I guess that would be my contention